# List not getting appended to Class Variable List in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, subset, backtracking

I am solving SUBSET 2 problem on leetcode in python.
Here is the link: https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets-ii/

Here, when I am printing subset one by one,its working fine,but when I try to append all subset in a list 'a' and return it, its return blank.
Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=[]
        self.arr=[]

    def subsetsWithDup(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:

        self.sq(0,self.arr,nums)
        # print(self.a)
        return self.a

    
    def sq(self,i,arr,nums):
        if i >=len(nums):
            # Solution.a.append(arr)
            
            print(arr)    ###This works fine,but return all subset on new line.
            # self.a.append(arr)   ### I want all subset in one list,but this isn't working.
            return 
        else:   
            t=nums[i]
            self.arr.append(nums[i])
            self.sq(i+1,self.arr,nums)
        # prev=t
            arr.remove(t)
            while i<len(nums)-1 :
                if nums[i+1]==t:
            #     i+=1
                    i+=1
                else:
                    break
            self.sq(i+1,self.arr,nums)
```

Comment: please indent your code properly. It's just one big syntax error otherwise

Comment: If this is the problem - *Given an integer array nums that may contain duplicates, return all possible subsets (the power set)*  Then the approach can be drastically simplified...